# How to add points and lines in ggplot for sums by years?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Year <- c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997)
Quarter <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
GDP <- c(19,20,23,24,15,16,18,19,34,18,14,19)

df <- data.frame(Year,Quarter,GDP)

   Year Quarter GDP
1  1995       1  19
2  1995       2  20
3  1995       3  23
4  1995       4  24
5  1996       1  15
6  1996       2  16
7  1996       3  18
8  1996       4  19
9  1997       1  34
10 1997       2  18
11 1997       3  14
12 1997       4  19
```

I would like to get a **plot with points for the sums of each year and a line connecting these points**. So far I have used

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=GDP))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="point")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

to get points for the sum for each year, but using `geom = "line"` instead (or even using both) returns an error:
    `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`

How would I make this plot with both points (representing sums) and a line connecting them? Thank you.

Edit 1: Adding `group = 1` in the `aes()` call of `ggplot` fixed the issue. @Ronak Shah suggested two possible solutions that work with this example data frame but not what I'm using for my project. Will investigate further.

Edit 2: Turns out the "Year" I was using was stored as `chr`; once I changed it to `num` everything worked as expected.

Comment: Did you try `geom_point()`+ `geom_line()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not first summarise and then plot?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(GDP = sum(GDP)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(Year, GDP) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After checking around on related questions (silly me), adding `group=1` in the `aes()` call fixes the issue.

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=GDP, group = 1))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="point")+
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="line")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: It also works without `group = 1`. Calling `stat_summary` twice fixes the issue.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Both of your solutions work for the example data frame I provided, but it gives me the same error when I use it on the original data set I'm exploring (if I use `group=1` there isn't an error). No clue why the difference, but thanks for the help!

Comment: @RonakShah Turns out the "Year" in my data was stored as `chr`; once I changed it to `num` your suggestions worked great! Thanks so much for the help!